# NextJS13 + React + MUI5 - unexplained padding and border added around Boxes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using React, NextJS13 and MUI5 to build a web app
For some users extra padding and border are added around Box elements that affects the page structure but are only shown in the Chrome Devtools visual debugger and not in the code debugger

The lines and border are added on all browsers I tested - Chrome, Safari, Edge and Firefox
I am unable to reproduce this on my machine, there are some users who have this happen consistently and some users that had this happen then stop with no apparent reason

All my users are on Macs with different versions of OSX (Ventura and Monterey) and identical versions of browsers

The first picture shows the added border lines with the padding and the second picture shows that Chrome Devtools only shows the padding and border in the visual debugger but not the code debugger
I would appreciate any help

Edit:
This is my `_app.tsx`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </Head>
  <CssBaseline />
  <Layout>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Layout>
</ThemeProvider>
```

[image: The gray border]

[image: It can be seen here that Chrome Devtools shows the padding and border in the visual debugger but not in the code debugger]

Comment: You are applying CSS Baseline? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/

Comment: Yes, I added my `_app.tsx` to the question body